# get dates from with specific time and date filter

Tags: php

I would like to get dates from tomorrow until 5 days with specify time and date values.

I tried this:

```
$date = date_create(date('d.m.Y 14:00:00'));

for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    
    date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));

    if ($date->format('w') >= 1 && $date->format('w') <= 5) {
        $dates[] = date_format($date, "d.m.Y H:i:s");
    }
    
    
    for ($y = 0; $y < 4; $y++) {
        
        if ($date->format('w') >= 1 && $date->format('w') < 5) {
        
            if ($date->format('H') >= 16) {
                        
                $dates[] = date_format($date, "d.m.Y H:i:s");
    
            }
            
        } elseif ($date->format('w') == 5) { 
            
            $dates[] = date_format($date, "d.m.Y H:i:s");
                
        }
        
        date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 hours"));
        
        
    }
    
    date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("-4 hours"));

}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 02.07.2021 14:00:00
    [1] => 02.07.2021 14:00:00
    [2] => 02.07.2021 15:00:00
    [3] => 02.07.2021 16:00:00
    [4] => 02.07.2021 17:00:00
    [5] => 05.07.2021 14:00:00
    [6] => 05.07.2021 16:00:00
    [7] => 05.07.2021 17:00:00
    [8] => 06.07.2021 14:00:00
    [9] => 06.07.2021 16:00:00
    [10] => 06.07.2021 17:00:00
)
```

But this is not correct.
It should be:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 02.07.2021 14:00:00
        [1] => 02.07.2021 15:00:00
        [2] => 02.07.2021 16:00:00
        [3] => 02.07.2021 17:00:00
        [4] => 02.07.2021 18:00:00
        [5] => 05.07.2021 16:00:00
        [6] => 06.07.2021 17:00:00
        [7] => 06.07.2021 18:00:00
    )
```

Summary:

I would like to get all dates where the day ist NOT saturday or sunday with thime 16,17,18 o'clock. Is it es Friday additional 14 and 15 o'clock.

Where is my mistake ? :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP >= 5.1:

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
function isWeekend($date) {
    $weekDay = date('w', strtotime($date));
    return ($weekDay == 0 || $weekDay == 6);
}
```

Comment: PHP 5.1 reached it's end of life over _14 years ago_ so there's not really any need post code for that version or earlier. Specially when the OP's code uses functions that didn't even exist then. Also, this alone won't solve all the issues with OP's code.